# Trying to start an activity using String variable and Class.forName keeps throwing ClassNotFound help please

Tags: java, android, class, android-intent

Hey I'm trying to start a new activity from this one using a String variable but every time I do it nothing happens. I'm assuming the program is just throwing the Class not found exception. Something is wrong with the Class.forName line. please check out my code and help. The only activity that ive created is the StartingPoint activity, the example activities won't work i know but it doesnt even work when i select StartingPoint. and when i change the intent line to "...new Intent(MenuActivity.this, Starting point.class)" it still doesnt work so I'm assuming it's throwing the exception already in the Class.forName() line because when i put that Intent(MenuActivity.this, Starting point.class)" outside of the try block it works!!!

```
package com.example.music;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MenuActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] classes = { "StartingPoint", "example1","example2", "example3",
        "example4", "example5", "example6"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MenuActivity.this,     
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}




@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName(cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}

}
```

Comment: When you get an exception or any error message, **always** post the full error message.

Comment: Also, do you know what `Class.forName` does? What arguments does it expect?

Comment: Post your logcat please

Answer (score 2):

You need to mention the fully qualified name.

```
Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.music."+cheese);
```

Also make sure the packagename matches the one mentioned in manifest file. Also make sure you declare all the activities in manifest.

```
public static Class<?> forName (String className)

Added in API level 1
Returns a Class object which represents the class with the given name. The name should be the name of a non-primitive class, as described in the class definition. Primitive types can not be found using this method; use int.class or Integer.TYPE instead.

If the class has not yet been loaded, it is loaded and initialized first. This is done through either the class loader of the calling class or one of its parent class loaders. It is possible that a static initializer is run as a result of this call.

Throws
ClassNotFoundException  if the requested class can not be found.
LinkageError    if an error occurs during linkage
ExceptionInInitializerError if an exception occurs during static initialization of a class.
```

> and when i change the intent line to "...new Intent(MenuActivity.this,
>   Starting point.class)" it still doesnt work so I'm assuming it's
>   throwing the exception already in the Class.forName() line because
>   when i put that Intent(MenuActivity.this, Starting point.class)"
>   outside of the try block it works

You still had `Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName(cheese);` and as you see it throws  `ClassNotFoundException` if the requested class can not be found. You go the excpetion because you din't mention the fully qualified name like `packaname.classname`